# Interpolating data only between first and last observation in R

Tags: r, linear-interpolation

I am a little stuck here and could use some help.
I am trying to interpolate some missing data in a time series, but a lot of my cases (countries) only have few observations and are often not consistent. So I am trying to interpolate beween the first observation and the last in for each country. How do I do that if there are some NAs left after the last observation in a country that I do not want to be interpolated?

```
library("tidyverse")
library("imputeTS")
data <- data.frame(country = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), 
               time = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1990, 1991, 1992), 
               value = c(5, 6, 7, NA, 5, NA, 7, 5, 6, 7))
print(data)


data %>% group_by(country) %>% 
 mutate(int = na_interpolation(value))
```

I would like the value for 1993 in country 1 to remain NA. Its probably simple, but I cant wrap my head around it.

Comment: Hi, what value you would like to put.hope this will help.```data$value <- ifelse(is.na(data$value),1,data$value)```

Comment: I would like the missing value in group 2 to be interpolated (in the example its 6, as the interpolation functino does), but the missing value in group 1 not, because its after the last value in that group (it turns out as 7 in this example, as 1 in yours).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the na.approx function in the "zoo" package.

```
library("zoo")
data %>% group_by(country) %>% mutate(int = na.approx(value, na.rm=FALSE))
```

Hope this is what you are looking for, This would keep the NA  in country 1 as NA.

Comment: Thanks, that was it!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try the following code using `lm` + `predict` (all `NA` will be predicted)

```
m <- lm(value ~ time + country, data)
data$value[is.na(data$value)] <- predict(m, newdata = subset(data,!!rowSums(is.na(data))))
```

such that

```
> data
   country time value
1        1 1990     5
2        1 1991     6
3        1 1992     7
4        1 1993     8
5        2 1990     5
6        2 1991     6
7        2 1992     7
8        3 1990     5
9        3 1991     6
10       3 1992     7
```

**EDIT**: 
Here is a base R solution that will keep `NA`  for 1993 in country 1

```
data <- do.call(rbind,
                c(lapply(split(data,data$country), 
                         function(v) within(v, value <- approx(time[!is.na(value)],value[!is.na(value)],time)$y)),
                  make.row.names = F)
                )
```

such that

```
> data 
   country time value
1        1 1990     5
2        1 1991     6
3        1 1992     7
4        1 1993    NA
5        2 1990     5
6        2 1991     6
7        2 1992     7
8        3 1990     5
9        3 1991     6
10       3 1992     7
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps me a little further down the line!

Comment: @H.Stevens I just noticed that you want to remain the value for 1993 in country 1 as `NA`. Besides the accepted answer, I added another solution which is a base R version